# How tranpose the data of more than 1 cell to only 1 cell on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I have the following column :

```
A1
Miu Kei Yuk
3354
of
2018
8 April 2022
```

and need to separate it into 3 columns :
`3354 of 2018` `Miu Kei Yuk`    `8 April 2022`

So the first and the fifth row are correct, but the row number 2, 3 and 4 needs to be in only 1 cell.

I tried transpose(A1:A5) but iu results in :

```
Miu Kei Yuk domingo, março 07, 1909 of  2018    8 April 2022
```

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
={A2&" "&A3&" "&A4, A1, A5}
```

[image]

or:

```
={A2&" "&A3&" "&A4\ A1\ A5}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Portuguese Locale** use this formula or [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kqxKZDDYsPYoDmhrmEyQftFsuLXqlrpDnecM93QAfEg/copy) of this example.

```
={TEXTJOIN(" ";1;A2:A4)\ 
  A1\
  A5}
```

[image]

**For United States locale use this formula**

```
={TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A2:A4), 
  A1,
  A5}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Vitor-Pinheiro the answer is updated.